# I keep getting this error "RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed"

Tags: reactjs, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory, vscode-debugger

I have been experiencing this for some days now. As I start working in my Vs Code, the terminal server, will suddenly stop working, showing the error message attached in the screenshot.

Please does anyone have any idea how I can fix this.

```
RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed
at new ArrayBuffer (<anonymous>)
at new Uint8Array (<anonymous>)
at new FastBuffer (node:internal/buffer:959:5)
at createUnsafeBuffer (node:internal/buffer:1062:12)
at Function.allocUnsafeSlow (node:buffer:385:10)
at read (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\food-delivery\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:597:32)  
at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\food-delivery\node_modules\webpack\lib\serialization\FileMiddleware.js:657:7
at C:\Users\USER\Desktop\food-delivery\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:362:16
at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)
```

PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\food-delivery>

[The Vs Code Screenshot below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2k1r.png)

Answer (score 10):

It might be related to your node version architecture.

Check your version running the command `node -p "process.arch"`

In my case, I had the 32 bits version. Installing node 64 bits solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was facing the same issue in my Angular project.

Answer (score 1):

run `node -p process.arch` If the output is x64, it means that the installed Node.js version is 64-bit. you might need to reinstall node for x64 If the output is x86, which means that the installed Node.js version is 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any large files in assets or any other folder in the source tree. If you have any remove them and try.

Answer (score 0):

Check your version running the command: ' **node -p "process.arch"** '
In my case, I had the 32 bits version. So I installed node 64 bits verison of it. It solved the issue.

***Methods to install 64 bit version over existing 32 bit***

1. Install Node directly from website. It will override the existing older 32 bit version then re-install the npm but globally this time and other modules or just add the path.
2. unistall all the existing node js and its dependencies from ur pc and then re-install the node js latest version
3. If still it doesnt work then it might be the case that your PC is not compatible or your project is too heavy to run